# Does CiviGroup Roles Sync work with bulk changes to groups?

Tags: drupal, groups, roles

Using CiviCRM 4.7.17 with Drupal 7.54

CiviGroup Roles sync adds and removes Drupal users from Drupal roles when changes to CiviGroup groups are done one Contact at a time from the groups tab for the Contact. So the sync is set up correctly.

But when I add or remove Contacts to/from CiviGroup groups in bulk from a list of Contacts, the changes are not synced to the Drupal roles.

These are NOT Smart groups by the way.

Am I missing something? How can I do bulk add/remove Contacts in Civi and have the Drupal roles synced accordingly?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

From what I understand CiviMember Role sync and CiviGroup Role sync auto-mapping - are evaluated at the time the User logs in.

Login -> is user in a specific Group -> ah yes -> so assign role x

So there really is no need to hit the sync button - I don't think; all is well on login.

Comment: Thanks KarinG. I can see that. CiviMember Role sync can be configured to sync when user logs in/out, during cron run, or when membership is updated. Because the individual group change is synced right away, without the user logging in/out, I expected the bulk group changes to also sync right away as well since there is no "when to sync" type of configuration for CiviGroup Roles sync.